# I'm having problems uploading images to mongodb using multer for my website hosted on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, multer

I'm creating a blog website and trying to give users the ability to upload profile pictures, I've been trying multer and various configurations, it keeps telling me  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/uploads/ either this or the request goes through but no image is saved can someone please help?

my user schema
``

````
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    profileImg:Buffer,
    googleId: String,
    facebookId:String,
    twitterId:String,
         created:{type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now}
     });
```

```multer stuff
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){

     cb(null,  './uploads');

},
filename : function(req, file, cb){
     cb(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
```
post request to update users profile

```
app.post("/profilepic", upload.single("image"), (req, res)=>{
 console.log(req.file);
  User.updateOne({_id:req.user._id}, {$set:{profileImg: req.body.filename}}, (err)=>{
    if(err){console.log(err);}else{res.redirect("/settings")}
  })
  console.log(req.user);
});

```

```
````

Comment: You shouldn't store images on the dyno anyway, they'll disappear on at least a daily basis: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted-from-the-application

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to save the file name, and not the actual file. In the schema you defined the profileImg property as Buffer, so you might read the file first (using the 'fs' node module) and then try to send it with the updateOne method.

Another way of storing your image is in a text field. You could convert the image stored on the server to base64 and then save it in the mongo. When you need the image, you get the base64 and convert it back to a file.